# Python - Dice Roller using Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I am using the application Canopy on a windows computer system. I am attempting to create a fun and simple dice rolling game. The game works, however I am not able to successfully add an image of a dice as the button for rolling. I seem to get an error I can't really find any resources on. I am only wondering If I am implementing things into the wrong place? Or if the image code will not even work whatsoever. I don't want people to do this for me, I just need a simple answer to if I'm completing this correctly and I only need to maybe touch some things up.
Thank you!

*Error provided from compilation:* **TclError: image "pyimage26" doesn't exist**

**Current standing code below...**

```
 import random
    import Tkinter
    from PIL import ImageTk, Image
    import os

    win = Tkinter.Tk()
    win.title("Die Roller")
    class die():
        import Tkinter
        def __init__(self,ivalue,parent):
            self.label_var = Tkinter.IntVar()
            self.label_var.set(ivalue)
            self.display = Tkinter.Label(parent,relief='ridge', borderwidth=4, 
                           textvariable=self.label_var)
            self.display.pack(side='left')

    img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("meme.jpg"))
    panel =Tkinter.Label(win, image =  img)
    panel.pack(side = "bottom", fill = "both", expand = "yes")
    win.mainloop()
    def roll(self):
            value = random.randint(1,6)
            self.label_var.set(value)
            print "You rolled =  ", value
    def rollin():
        d1.roll()
        d2.roll()
        d3.roll()
    row1 = Tkinter.Frame(win)
    row2 = Tkinter.Frame(win)
    d1 = die(1,row1)
    d2 = die(1,row1)
    d3 = die(1,row1)
    row1.pack()
    rolldice = Tkinter.Button(row2, command=rollin, text = "Roll The Die")
    rolldice.pack()
    row2.pack()
    win.mainloop()
```

Comment: first you need to fix your indentation, second, that error is cause by not keeping a reference to the image, so pythons garbage collector cleans it up. simply assign it to your class using something like `self.img=...` instead of `img=...` and use the `self.img` reference in your label

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just reformatted your code so that the scopes make any sense and came up with:

```
import random
import Tkinter
from PIL import ImageTk, Image

class die():                                                                 
    def __init__(self,ivalue,parent):                                        
        self.label_var = Tkinter.IntVar()                                    
        self.label_var.set(ivalue)                                           
        self.display = Tkinter.Label(parent,relief='ridge', borderwidth=4,
                                              textvariable=self.label_var)
        self.display.pack(side='left')                                       

    def roll(self):                                                          
            value = random.randint(1,6)                                      
            self.label_var.set(value)                                        
            print "You rolled =  ", value                                    

def rollin():                                                                
    d1.roll()                                                                
    d2.roll()                                                                
    d3.roll()                                                                

if __name__=="__main__":                                                     
    win = Tkinter.Tk()                                                       
    win.title("Die Roller")                                                  
    row1 = Tkinter.Frame(win)                                                
    row2 = Tkinter.Frame(win)                                                
    d1 = die(1,row1)                                                         
    d2 = die(1,row1)                                                         
    d3 = die(1,row1)                                                         
    row1.pack()                                                              
    rolldice = Tkinter.Button(row2, command=rollin, text = "Roll The Die")   
    rolldice.pack()                                                          
    row2.pack()                                                              
    img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("meme.jpg"))                     
    panel =Tkinter.Label(win, image =  img)                                  
    panel.pack(side = "bottom", fill = "both", expand = "yes")               
    win.mainloop()
```

You have some issues in your code.
First, you use `win.mainloop()` two times which does not make any sense.

Second, you have to make sure your scope is correct. Global Image variable `img` inside the code above (mine) is declared inside *global* scope.

Yours gets deleted outside the class. Therefore it is no longer available.

Your os import (`import os`) is unused so i removed it.

Always remember to format your code not only for calling in python but also keep it clean and use the scope functionalities given by the language (e.g. `if __name__=="__main__"` constructs which keep the global scope.

Comment: Thank you so much for doing that. I very much appreciate it. Your help was amazing!